# how to see where exactly torch is installed pip vs conda torch installation

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

On my machine i can't "pip install torch" - i get infamous "single source externally managed error" - i could not fix it and used "conda install torch" from anaconda.

Still, checking version is easy - `torch.__version__`

But how to see where is it installed -the home dir of torch?
Suppose if I had had both torches installed via pip and conda - how to know which one is used in a project?

```
import torch
print(torch__version__)
```

Comment: In a single environment, only one torch version will be installed. it doesnot matter that by which method its installed either pip or conda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get torch module location which is imported in your script

```
import torch
print(torch.__file__)
```

Comment: there is also torch.__path__

Answer (score 4):

`pip show torch` at terminal will give you all the required information.

```
Name: torch
Version: 1.3.1
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/
Author: PyTorch Team
Author-email: packages@pytorch.org
License: BSD-3
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy
Required-by: torchvision, torchtext, efficientunet-pytorch
```

Comment: thx u @Mughees, but pip show torch gives me "package not found"

Comment: have you created conda enviornment? if yes, activate that and then see

Comment: you are using linux?

Comment: damn, i should ve specified it, no i m on win10 x64

Comment: for next questions i will always specify what OS i use

Comment: okay then use anaconda prompt(not cmd) to test the specified command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already installed **PyTorch** library, then open **Google Colab**, paste following code and hit the **run button**:

```
import torch
print(torch.__file__)
```

then you see version of **PyTorch**.

If it is not working then please go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and follow the instruction about how to install **PyTorch** because sometimes **Python** and **PyTorch** have dependencies issues.